# Rails: Is it possible to reference a instance variable (like @user.color_preferred) with an interpolated string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm trying to change the background color with the field color_preferred defined in the model `User`.

/* file example.css.scss.erb */

```
$color: <%= @user.color_preferred %>; 


body {
    background-color: $color;
    color: #333;
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px; }
```

Is it possible to access the ruby instance variables from sass files?
Tk.
Rafa.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, it's not possible. Sass gets compiled on deployment (in Rails 3.1), afterwards it is a static file. It would not make any sense, either. The css files should be independent of the user and be cachable for a long time.

Why don't you insert a style tag inside of your layout and overwrite the default style defined inside your css, if the user has chosen a preferred color?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this by extending [Sass::Script::Functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html). Simply create a ruby file, add this bit in, and then load it into your script's environment (i.e. /config/initializers/):

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def var(name)
    assert_type name, :String, :name
    @environment.var(name.value)
  end

  declare :var, :args => [:string]
end
```

Then you can do stuff like this:

```
$button-primary-bg: #000;
$button-secondary-bg: #123;
$button-tertiary-bg: #abc;

$button-names: (primary, secondary);

@each $name in $names {
  .button-#{$name} { background: var("button-#{$name}-bg"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it involves hacking through Sass and going deep into it. The better way is like iGel said, create different "themes" and include that to your body depending on the user's preference.

Say you have a main.css and some theming colors(say a different body-background depending on the user's choice)

```
 = stylesheet_include_tag 'main'
 = stylesheet_include_tag "#{@user.color_preferred}"
```

then you have some colors premade like blue.sass, red.sass, green.sass, etc.

it is easy to generate these as you can just use a variable like you did in your example except that you have to reproduce it to support different colors.